# I have a seemingly untraceable hang with Ubuntu/Mono/C#. How can I find it?

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono

I've got a server program running on Ubuntu and it hangs after a few clients connect.  The thing is, it only does it when not being debugged in the IDE.  I can run it (the exact same debug binaries) from a command line, attach gdb to it, and it will hang, but gdb finds no problem.  When I debug from MonoDevelop, however, it never hangs.

I am at a complete loss for how to proceed from here.

Does anyone know if Mono sets some flags or something I'm not aware of?  I'm crucially blocked and completely frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, don't let the Console IO get clogged, because there are almost no indicators.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a race condition somewhere - MonoDevelop uses soft debugger, which slows execution down as a side effect, so the livelihood of a lock decreases. Or you can try this: http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging#Debugging_Unmanaged_Deadlocks

Comment: Turns out the console IO buffer got clogged.  Which apparently causes the program to simply hang.